# Split plot with RBCD in R: Are inferences valid when output reports some effects are not estimable?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, split-plot

Data are from an agricultural experiment and are the proportion of turnips damaged by cabbage maggot in different insecticide treatments (note preliminary investigation suggested data were approximately normal and homoskedastic). There were three whole-plot treatments applied at planting time ("atplant") arranged in 5 randomized complete blocks ("block"). Each whole plot was split into three subplots assigned one of three postplant treatments ("postplant"). "Wholeplot" indicates the wholeplot number.

I ran an analysis of variance using the below R code:

```
block = factor(c('I','I','I','I','I','I','I','I','I','II','II','II','II','II','II','II','II','II','III','III','III','III','III','III','III','III','III','IV','IV','IV','IV','IV','IV','IV','IV','IV','V','V','V','V','V','V','V','V','V'))
wholeplot= factor(c('1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','4','5','5','5','6','6','6','7','7','7','8','8','8','9','9','9','10','10','10','11','11','11','12','12','12','13','13','13','14','14','14','15','15','15'))
atplant=factor(c('lorsban','lorsban','lorsban','sepresto','sepresto','sepresto','untreated','untreated','untreated','untreated','untreated','untreated','sepresto','sepresto','sepresto','lorsban','lorsban','lorsban','sepresto','sepresto','sepresto','untreated','untreated','untreated','lorsban','lorsban','lorsban','lorsban','lorsban','lorsban','untreated','untreated','untreated','sepresto','sepresto','sepresto','untreated','untreated','untreated','lorsban','lorsban','lorsban','sepresto','sepresto','sepresto'))
postplant=factor(c('untreated','mlo','mhi','untreated','mlo','mhi','untreated','mhi','mlo','mhi','mlo','untreated','mlo','untreated','mhi','mhi','mlo','untreated','mlo','untreated','mhi','untreated','mhi','mlo','mhi','mlo','untreated','mhi','untreated','mlo','mlo','mhi','untreated','untreated','mlo','mhi','mhi','mlo','untreated','mlo','untreated','mhi','mlo','untreated','mhi'))     
numdam = c(25,15,13,23,17,16,24,9,26,12,17,27,22,19,7,5,9,13,18,23,19,38,30,22,16,14,30,24,26,34,38,34,32,37,18,7,12,27,25,13,22,5,32,25,2)
numundam = c(20,30,32,22,28,29,21,36,19,33,28,18,23,26,38,40,36,32,22,22,26,7,15,23,29,31,15,19,19,11,7,11,11,8,27,38,33,18,20,32,23,40,13,20,43)
propdam = round(numdam/(numdam+numundam),2)
vz19 = data.frame(block,wholeplot,atplant,postplant,propdam)
fit.aov = aov(propdam~atplant*postplant + block + Error(wholeplot), data=vz19)
summary(fit.aov)
fit.aov
```

The ANOVA results seem reasonable, but the output warns that "4 out of 10 effects not estimable, Estimated effects may be unbalanced" for the wholeplot stratum.

I averaged the response variable across subplots and did a simple RBCD ANOVA on the response at the whole-plot level, and the P-values are identical. Given this, I suspect the error is not critical but before publishing results I want to make sure inferences are sound.

---

> Call: aov(formula = propdam ~ atplant * postplant + block +
>   Error(wholeplot), 
>       data = vz19)
>
> Grand Mean: 0.4584444
>
> Stratum 1: wholeplot
>
> Terms:
>                     atplant     block Residuals Sum of Squares  0.2188978 0.4927022 0.1578578 Deg. of Freedom         2         4         8
>
> Residual standard error: 0.1404714 4 out of 10 effects not estimable
>   Estimated effects may be unbalanced
>
> Stratum 2: Within
>
> Terms:
>                   postplant atplant:postplant Residuals Sum of Squares  0.5285644         0.0420089 0.4825600 Deg. of Freedom         2                 4        24
>
> Residual standard error: 0.141798 Estimated effects may be unbalanced